# Changing icon unicode on element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I have a form with one two inputs. One of them is for text input and the another one is for submit, like a button. I added an icon in that submit one and I want to change it on click.

```
<input class="searchBtn" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="&#xf002">


$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(".searchInput").on("click", function () {
        $(".searchBtn").attr("value", "&#xf105")
    })
})
```

The first icon works fine with that unicode value, but when I click it shows `&#xf105`, not the icon for which that is the unicode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `$(".searchInput").val` should be `$(".searchInput").val()` and `$(".searchBtn").attr("value", "&#xf105")` should be `$(".searchBtn").val("&#xf105")`. Come to think of it, why does `var a = $(".searchInput").val` exist at all? It doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: I was testing something with `$(".searchInput").val()` and forgot to delete it. You are right, it does nothing. I tried `$(".searchBtn").val("&#xf105")` but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution (use the sequence `\u` to escape):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(".search-btn").on("click", evt => {
        $(evt.target).attr("value", "\uf105");
    })
})
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.search-btn {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="search-btn" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="&#xf002">
```

Comment: I'm using Flask - Forms so it generates this as an input.

Comment: @IvanKojic, I've just improved my solution so you can use it in the input component.